# How to search for multiple strings in a vi editor on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, vi

I tried using
`/string1\|string2`
didn't work.
Tried
`/string1|string2`
didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the 'alternations' inside a 'grouping' of \(...\). This should work:

```
/\(string1\|string2\)
```

Comment: I am searching for `===>>` and `<<===` ... Tried `\(===>>\|<<===\)`, didn't work.

Comment: Which version of vi are you on? Works on VIM 7.3, including in compatible mode. Just to check, are you trying `/\(===>>\|<<===\)` ?

Comment: `:ve` gives me `Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0`. The Solaris OS is 5.10 though.

Comment: Yes I am using `/\(===>>\|<<===\)`.

Answer (score 1):

To search for `foo` or `bar` you can do this:

```
/[fb][oa][or]
```

but that's not very scalable :)

Solaris 10 native `vi(1)` doesn't support regex alternation. See BREs (basic regular expressions) in `regex(5)` (`man -s5 regex`).

Solaris 11 ships with `vim`.

Comment: It works, no doubt, but what's the point of having a feature when no one's going to use it. Thanks Martin.